# Finding optimal lag order for an exogenous regressor in a VAR model

Tags: r, time-series, vector-autoregression, lags

I can't use VARselect as it gives lags in a VAR model which considers all the variables to be endogenous. In my case, one of the variables is exogenous and affects dependent variable with a certain lag.

Is there any package or function in R which can help me find the optimal lag order of the exogenous regressor?

Comment: I tried to shorten the title so as not to scare people away :) If you find my edit not satisfactory, feel free to undo. By the way, I am not aware of any functions to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest constructing a transfer function (single endogenous model) using identifiable lag structure for all the inputs. Care should be taken to consider any necessary level shifts/local time trends/seasonal and regular pulses along with any necessary ARIMA structure to account for unspecified/omitted stochastic inputs. The more general solution is a Vector ARIMA model with user specified exogenous series but this is largely intractable/unavailable when Gaussian Violations are present as they almost nearly are.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, as far as I know, it is:

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(50), x2 = rnorm(50))
model <- VARselect(df, exogen = cbind(x3 = rnorm(50)))
model

$selection
AIC(n)  HQ(n)  SC(n) FPE(n) 
     1      1      1      1 

$criteria
               1         2         3         4         5        6         7
AIC(n) 0.3819556 0.5409510 0.5559532 0.6966488 0.7490992 0.721105 0.8037243
HQ(n)  0.5040847 0.7241447 0.8002114 1.0019715 1.1154865 1.148557 1.2922407
SC(n)  0.7197315 1.0476148 1.2315050 1.5410885 1.7624269 1.903321 2.1548279
FPE(n) 1.4671137 1.7254929 1.7627647 2.0509437 2.1971864 2.187764 2.4554746
               8         9       10
AIC(n) 0.9664021 0.8381916 0.616336
HQ(n)  1.5159831 1.4488371 1.288046
SC(n)  2.4863936 2.5270711 2.474103
FPE(n) 3.0198382 2.8162782 2.434792
```